# Access to path 'd:/' denied while trying to add an xml file as web reference

Tags: asp.net, salesforce, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to add a reference to a wsdl file. When i try to add a web reference i get a error saying

> there was an error downloading d: Access to the path d: is denied.

I am on a windows 8 and using vs2013 ultimate with iisexpress. 
I understand that its related to permissions. I tried giving out full access to the directory for everyone.

Its been over 5 yrs since i had opened visual studio and lots have changed from the days of vs2005. This could be something very simple, bear with me if i sound too ignorant..

Answer (score 3):

add the full file name to the file path  e.g.

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\enterprise.wsdl.xml
```

simple but very confusing!

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the WSDL to \Inetpub\wwwroot and then trying to reference it there.